# Why is this statement "The number of negative and positive charges in the Universe does not change" false?

Tags: electrostatics, conservation-laws, charge, universe

I am not able to understand why this is false given that total charge in a system is conserved. Does this mean that charge can be created or destroyed such that sum of charge remains same?

Comment: When a neutron decays to a proton, an electron and a neutrino, a neutral particle has decayed into two charged and a neutral particle. The sum of charges is unchanged, but both positive and negative charge increased.

Comment: I am actually not super-sure if you are referring to the effect of [Black Hole Evaporation][1]... check it out eventually!


  [1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0010055

Comment: @PietroOliva I am taking just taking introductory electro-magnetism course on OCW and this statement came up. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @scaphys thanks, now i understood it.

Comment: @scaphys Greetings! We prefer that comments be used to improve the post they’re attached to, and that answers (even short ones) be posted as answers. Please consider converting yours here.

Comment: This appears to be confusion between "total charge"  and "net charge,"   where the former really means "total number of charged particles" and of course the latter refers to the sum charge over all particles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in my universe, there are $3$ electron charges and $4$ positrons, so that there is $1$ unit of positive charge. Then one day a photon reacts via
$$\gamma \rightarrow e+e^+$$

so that now there are $4$ electrons and $5$ positrons. That makes your statement wrong! While still, the total charge remains $1$ unit.

---

Edit: Please find the details of the pair production [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production).

I haven't gotten into the details about the universe, but I think the central idea is clear. But as raised by a question in a comment, $1$ electron is bound to a proton making a nucleus and the others are free. The pair production takes place near this atom so that the momentum conservation remains valid.

Comment: This reaction cannot conserve momentum an energy.

Comment: Yeah! The reaction must take place near nuclei.  I have added the link who wants the details

Comment: You started out with a universe without nuclei.

Comment: Please find edit'

Comment: A less controversial reaction is $\gamma+\gamma \to e^- + e^+$; that this usually happens near nuclei with one real and one virtual photon is then a detail rather than a fundamental assumption.